# I get the same output for a classifier algorithm with sklearn and pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

## Problem

I get the same output everytime regardless of the input.

## Context

I have a .csv with IDs that represent a team of 5 persons (previously formed teams) like this:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 3, 8
2, 5, 6, 7, 3
9, 1, 2, 6, 4
9, 0, 1, 2, 4
...
```

My goal with the following code is to be able to input 4 IDs and get a prediction of what the 5th member should be.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import pandas as pd 

file = 'People.csv'

# Read dataset without a header row:
dataset = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)

# return the first 5 rows: 
dataset.head() 

# Convert input to a two-dimensional array:
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

# Split dataset into random train and test subsets:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)

# Standardize - removes mean and scales to unit variance:
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test) 

# Use the KNN classifier to fit data:
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train) 

# Uses the classifier to predict the value of the fifth column:
y_pred = classifier.predict([[5, 6, 7, 3]])

# Print the predicted value:
print(y_pred)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainstream statistical machine learning assumes that it's possible to predict an **attribute** of an object based on **other observed attributes**.

In the problem presented here: there are no attributes. Each row represents a previously observed team, and each column represents an **identifier attribute** of a team member. In other words: it is not clear how we would build a model.

---

There's an alternate way to frame this problem though: "*Which people prefer to work together?*" or "*[What frequent patterns exist in this data?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequent_pattern_discovery)*" or "*[How do we expect each person to rate one another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering)?*"

"[Apriori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm)" is an algorithm that helps estimate which objects (team members) frequently appear together, and [`mlxtend`](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/) provides an implementation:

```py
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 3, 8],
    [2, 5, 6, 7, 3],
    [9, 1, 2, 6, 4],
    [9, 0, 1, 2, 4],
]


te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(data).transform(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)

print(apriori(df, min_support=0.5))
```

The output includes `itemsets` and their `support` (basically a measure of how frequently they were observed together).

```
   support   itemsets
0      0.6        (1)
1      0.8        (2)
2      0.6        (3)
3      0.6        (4)
4      0.6        (6)
5      0.6     (1, 2)
6      0.6     (1, 4)
7      0.6     (2, 4)
8      0.6  (1, 2, 4)
```

For example: this tells us that user `2` has previously appeared in 80% of the teams, and this tells us that users `1`, `2`, and `4` worked together 60% of the time.

If we were trying to form groups in the future: we might sample from users who worked with one another previously, and randomly add or remove people until everyone was on a team.

Comment: This is really interesting, but with this approach could we input 4 or 3 or ... x? to see the "favorite" 5-member team that likes to work together?

Comment: Try running with `min_support=0.2`, which will show all possible itemsets here. There are five "favorite" five-member teams which correspond to the five teams observed in the data. If you have a larger dataset and observe multiple cases of `[9, 1, 2, 6, 4]`, it may signal that team works together frequently.

Comment: For this "team formation" task, an approach might be: (1) randomly choose according to past preferences, (2) randomly assign from remaining people until five people are reached.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate approach where we try to model the preferences of *exactly* 10 users.

This has some downsides I'll mention at the end.

We'll ignore the `train_test_split` while we're exploring. And we'll take note that we have identifiers for users `0` through `9`, making this a 10-class-classification problem:

```py
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

data_file = StringIO("""0, 1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 3, 8
2, 5, 6, 7, 3
9, 1, 2, 6, 4
9, 0, 1, 2, 4""")

data = np.loadtxt(data_file, delimiter=",")
classes = np.unique(data)
# array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
```

We'll also assume that we can model "*Who is missing?*" with a neural network:

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

model = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(20, 100, 20))
```

We might think of this as "*leave one user out, and predict the missing person.*" e.g.: if we see `[0, 1, 2, 3, _]`, we want to predict `4` since we observe `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` in our `data`.

But wait: what should we predict if we observe: `[0, 1, 3, 2]`?

This might be an *invariant* of the problem. The prediction should be invariant under permutation of our inputs, or these should be equal `[0, 1, 2, 3, _] == [0, 1, 3, 2, _]` This also means we need to use a more complex training method where we permute our `data` along the rows and perform partial fits. For 10 users and groups of 5, there are `10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 == 30_240` possible teams we could observe, so we might also repeat this training loop on many random instances:

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = default_rng()

for _ in range(15_000):
    # Perform partial fits on batches of permuted data.

    batch = rng.permutation(data, axis=1)

    X_batch = batch[:, :4]
    y_batch = batch[:, 4]

    model.partial_fit(X_batch, y_batch, classes=classes)

plt.plot(model.loss_curve_)
plt.show()
```

The `15_000` chosen here is pretty arbitrary, but the loss appears to be decreasing steadily:

[image: Loss over the network, showing steady decrease over 15,000 iterations]

We now have a model that should be able to predict "*who is the missing person*?"

At prediction time we want to answer: who is missing from the set `[0, 1, 2, 3]`? But remember: we trained on examples where we permuted the inputs, so there's a chance that passing `[3, 2, 1, 0]` through the network gives a different answer.

One way to remedy this could be by permuting a test example 100 times, passing all of them through the network, and observing the *average* result across the permutations (these examples are small enough you could exhaustively test every case, but this would not scale to larger sets).

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

def make_predictions(team, ax=None, title=None):
    # team: np.array([[5, 6, 7, 3]])
    # Warning: mutates `team`

    predictions = []

    for _ in range(100):
        rng.shuffle(team, axis=1)
        predictions.append(model.predict_proba(team).flatten())

    predictions = np.asarray(predictions).mean(axis=0)

    ax.bar(range(10), predictions)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

    return predictions
```

We now have enough written to see what the model predicts across a variety of inputs. We observed `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` in the input data, but what does this model predict when given: `[0, 1, 2, _, _]`?

Let's find out:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 7, sharey=True)

for i, ax in zip([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], axs):
    _ = make_predictions(np.array([[0, 1, 2, i]]), ax, title=f'[0, 1, 2, {i}, _]')

plt.show()
```

[image: Seven histograms showing the probabilityof each class. 4 is extremely likely when the network observes 0 1 2 3. The network is uncertain when it observes 0 1 2 4.]

This gives some insight to where the problem is less certain. The case of `[0, 1, 2, 4, _]` suggests that `3` has ~40% and `9` has ~55%. This also reflects that in the training data, we saw both: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[0, 1, 2, 4, 9]`.

### Is this a good approach?

Probably not. This assumes we have *exactly* 10 people that we are repeatedly making teams of 5 for.

The final example also helps show that there is inherent uncertainty in this problem, and a simpler approach like the one used in the [Apriori answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74790868/12439119) took far less work, is more interpretable, and can be tuned with heuristic background knowledge as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your model is not "learning" anything. If your output is not changing with the input, you may have a [Bias problem](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-bias-variance-tradeoff-165e6942b229) there.
The first thing you should check is how the classes are distributed (if it is extremely [imbalanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065833/imbalance-in-scikit-learn) this could be the reason why you are having this problem)

Answer (score 0):

I used another model with a different approach to solve my problem. With the same dataset, I was able to get better results. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

# Load the dataset of previously formed teams and their corresponding 5th members
data = pd.read_csv("People.csv")

# Split the data into input features (4 IDs) and the target variable (5th ID)
X = data[["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"]]
y = data["A5"]

# Split the data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

# Create a neural network model
model = MLPClassifier()

# Train the model on the training data
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluate the model on the test data
accuracy = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)

# Use the trained model to make predictions on new teams of 4 IDs
team = [5, 6, 7, 3]
predicted_id = model.predict([team])
print("Predicted 5th member:", predicted_id)
```

Comment: This might work. One way to test it would be generate all permutations of `X` and `y` and perform `partial_fit` on batches until convergence: but this would be pretty inefficient. I think permutation-invariant neural networks are still an open research problem.

Comment: I'm new and trying to build models that fit my necessities without even knowing if they are efficient... by any chance is there a place where I could reference problems? It's like a rabbit hole, I keep finding and finding things without really knowing what is what and what could work or not. It's not my area of expertise clearly.

Comment: I added [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74792316/12439119) implementing something similar to my suggestion, and the final part suggests that the neural network approach ends up being similar to Apriori but is less interpretable and takes a lot of work to reach.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for your other question :( I think it comes down to experience and domain knowledge. Asking questions and trying different things is good though: [sucking at something is the first step to being kinda good at something](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gu8YiTeU9XU).